# Simulink: implementing a custom transfer function

Tags: matlab, simulink

Let's say I implement this m-file:

```
Fq=tf(0.5^2,[1 2*0.7*0.5 0.5^2]);
G=tf(0.006*[200 1],[80 1 0]);
Q=Fq/G;

open Inner_Loop.mdl
```

Inside Inner_loop.mdl, if I want to implement/model a transfer function block using G, how can it be achieved easily? In other words, how can I retrieve the numerator and denominator of a tf easily?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done by calling tfdata() function, for numerator data of let's say num, num{1} needs to be specified in the data fields of the transfer function block in the Simulink model.